# managing multiple versions of JDK: invalid source release error

Tags: java

I have jdk 1.6 and 1.7 installed.

I have updated my JAVA_HOME variable to

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_24;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0
```

But when I try to run java code.

```
>javac -version
javac 1.6.0_24

>java -version
java version "1.7.0_09"

>javac -source 1.7.0 -target 1.7.0 Test.java
javac: invalid source release: 1.7.0
```

Comment: i guess you´re using some different versions of JRE and JDK, seems like you´re jdk is still on 1.6

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` should point to one version or the other, not both.

Comment: @Ian Roberts, So practically I will be able to work with only version.

Comment: no, you can. The System checks the Java versions in a special order. This order is written down your system PATH variable. The jdk written first, will be used first.

Comment: Any given project/application will only use one version at any one time, but you can set different values of `JAVA_HOME` in different command windows, or if you use an IDE such as Eclipse you can register several different JDKs with that and point different projects at each one, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Your jdk is still pointing to JDK 1.6. javac is bundled with jdk, while java -version ideally runs even if jre is installed properly.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution would be to use the java_home tool.

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7.0_51 --exec javac -version
```

Comment: When running this, I get: 

`$ /usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7.0_51 --exec javac -version
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.7.0_51".
javac 1.6.0_65`

Comment: You can check on `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/` for the versions you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

Your "javac -version" test shows that you are using javac 1.6. Then you are trying to build for 1.7 which is a future version that is unknown to the 1.6 compiler. I would do as some comments suggests and only define one JDK for a given project.

Answer (score 0):

What about `javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7 Test.java`?