# IntelliJ: scala: javac: invalid source release: 1.7

Tags: java, scala, maven, intellij-idea, ide

I recently upgraded a Maven project to Java 7.

I use IntelliJ, and with Java 6, I could run my JUnit tests out of the IDE.  This was convenient because it was a quick way to debug a failing test.

Since upgrading to 7 I get the following error when I try to Run a test:

```
scala: javac: invalid source release: 1.7
scala: Usage: javac <options> <source files>
scala: use -help for a list of possible options
```

I'm on OS X 10.8.5 and IntelliJ 12.1.6.  Any help fixing these errors would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645643/managing-multiple-versions-of-jdk-invalid-source-release-error

Comment: Doesn't do the trick both `javac -version` and `java -version` are showing `1.7.0_45` for me from the console.

Comment: Ok, but your IntelliJ is still using an older version of Java, not Java 7. Check your Project Settings and make sure to set the Project SDK to Java 7.

Comment: can you provide more detals of your pom.xml? do you use the scala-maven-plugin and the maven-compiler-plugin with a correct version of java set?

Answer (score 0):

Does your setup look anything like this ? 
    
        UTF-8
        1.6

....

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <args>
                    <!--<arg>-unchecked</arg>-->
                    <!--<arg>-deprecation</arg>-->
                    <!--<arg>-explaintypes</arg>-->
                </args>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                     </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Non-sequitur?  What is your answer?