# java requirements in Apache Spark

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, installation

I am trying to build Apache Spark on a Mac. Since I use Macports, the Homebrew option is not feasible. So I manually installed the right version of java and maven and created the right paths:

```
Sankha-desktop:spark-1.6.1 user$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-11T00:41:47+08:00)
Maven home: /opt/local/share/java/maven33
Java version: 1.7.0_79, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home:
    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.11.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Now when I try to install Spark, I get the following error:

```
Sankha-desktop:spark-1.6.1 user$ build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -DskipTests clean package
Using `mvn` from path: /opt/local/share/java/maven33/bin/mvn
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 

~~~~~~~ some more stuff ~~~~~~~

[info] Compiling 3 Java sources to /Users/user/Documents/installers/spark/spark-1.6.1/tags/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] javac: invalid source release: 1.7
[error] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
[error] use -help for a list of possible options
[error] Compile failed at Apr 11, 2016 6:14:07 AM [0.024s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Spark Project Parent POM ........................... SUCCESS [  7.176 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Test Tags ............................ FAILURE [  1.027 s]
[INFO] Spark Project Launcher ............................. SKIPPED  
[INFO] Spark Project Networking ........................... SKIPPED
```

Apparently my java version is wrong? I explicitly installed version 1.7, and linked to it. I also have the latest version 1.8, but I already removed that from the JAVA_PATH.

Anyone knows what is going on?

Comment: I think it's similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645643/managing-multiple-versions-of-jdk-invalid-source-release-error

Comment: I did check that. Actually both my java and javac are 1.7. Ill try changing the zinc compiler settings later as described by Mark later whe I reach home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to the Zinc compiler.

I was able to get it to compile by disabling the Zinc compiler in the pom.xml file. Change this:

```
<useZincServer>true</useZincServer>
```

to this:

```
<useZincServer>false</useZincServer>
```

My error message was a little bit different as the Zinc compiler was looking for `javac` in my JRE directory. I tried to figure out how to set a different java_home for Zinc, but couldn't figure it out (there is a -java-home argument, and I tried to add it to the pom, but it didn't seem to have an effect).

Here is the Spark documentation regarding Zinc:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#speeding-up-compilation-with-zinc

Here is the Zinc GitHub page:

https://github.com/typesafehub/zinc

UPDATE: This may be an issue in the scala-maven-plugin - https://github.com/davidB/scala-maven-plugin/issues/173

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm. Looks like the current implementation uses some deprecated features. Hopefully everything will be patched soon!